# Splitting a table into two tables randomly with 50-50 percent of records in impala

Tags: string-splitting, impala

I have a table having n number of records in impala. I need to find out how can I divide that table into two equal halves with 50 - 50 percent of records in each.

Comment: This post shows no research or effort on your part.  What have you search for, tried, and found to not work?

Answer (score 1):

I assume that that you have 3 tables with identical structure, where the first has the data while the two others are empty.
I also assume that the tables or at least `table1` has a primary key.

Searching through the Impala SQL documentation, I don't find any window functions, so a `ROW_NUMBER()` solution is out of the question.

We could use a random function to split the table in 2 (almost equal) halves.:

```
-- insert half of the rows into table 2
INSERT INTO table2
SELECT *
FROM table1
WHERE rand() < 0.50 ;

-- insert the rest rows into table 3
INSERT INTO table3
SELECT t1.*
FROM table1 AS t1
  LEFT JOIN table2 AS t2
    ON t1.pk = t2.pk
WHERE t1.pk IS NULL ;
```

After that, we can drop `table1`.